# AngularJs directive template not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a problem with AngularJs directive.
The directive is working fine when I'm using "template". But when I'm trying to work with "templateURL".

The js file of the directive and the html file for the template are in the same directory. In the template file theres the same code as in the template field in my directive.

[image: my directive]

[image: project tree]

Why is this not working? I don't understand it.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't see any question here!

Comment: The templateUrl in your directive, are you setting a path to the correct file? `templateUrl: "test.html"`

Comment: Could you create a plunker ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the absolute path for the `templateUrl` field. Try this,

```
templateUrl : 'js/directive/test.html'
```

Comment: I tried to change it to your solution but it isn't working. Sorry, I'm new to AngularJS

Comment: Looked on it a second time. Your answer is correct without the first backslash. But I don't understand why this is working. Is there an easy explanation for that? My thought was that the js file and html file are in the same directory. So i could just write test.html into the directive.

Comment: templateUrl field will look for path/to/the/template. It cant take a file name and load it. So you have to specify the path instead of file name. Thanks.